# Shell Script: Copy directory passed as variable to another directory also as variable passed by user

Tags: linux, shell, copy, cp

SHELL SCRIPT:
How can i copy a directory passed as a variable by user to another directory also as variable?

I mean, the user type a source directory and the destination. So, the files into directory are copied to the other directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if cp -R "$source" "$destination"
then echo "Copy successful :)"
else echo "Copy failed :("
fi
```

The `-R` option to `cp` specifies that it should copy the directory recursively. `$source` should contain the original directory, and `$destination` should contain the location where you want it copied.

Comment: it says that cp: missing file operand

Comment: If it says that, you didn't set `$source` and `$destination` correctly.

Comment: That's file as long as you assign `source=$0` and `destination=$1` in the script. Or just use `$0` and `$1` in the command line in the answer. I assume you know enough about scripting to know how to use variables.

Comment: Oh! Great! I got it! And how can i print a message of OK if the directory was copied succesfully?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like this:

```
$ ./script.sh file1.ext file2.ext
```

The `script.sh` could be:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -rv "$0" "$1"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You need to quote the variables in case of whitespace.